# How to use client GPU over remote desktop?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I want to test my software on a clean virtual machine.

Downloaded Win10 vmware image from Microsoft.com, only to discover vmware doesn’t support Direct3D 11, it only supports DirectX 10, that’s almost 15 years old now. My software doesn’t work on 10.0.

I remember couple years ago, Microsoft remote desktop was able to use client GPU. No longer works, apparently MS switched to using server’s GPU with h264 video encoder.

How to fix?

This screenshot shows what I see in dxdiag from remote desktop, clearly that’s not Microsoft remote GPU, and my application fails on startup saying  feature level 11.0 is not supported.

[image]

Here’s a screenshot from group policy editor.

[image]

Comment: [The next version of VMWare Workstation supports DX11](https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/05/directx-11-now-with-workstation-tp20h2.html).  You need a Hypervisor that supports DX11.  Hyper-V not VirtualBox support DX11

Comment: @Ramhound I think they lied in the press release: http://const.me/tmp/vmware-about.png

Comment: I noticed that article was from May 2020.  [VMWare Workstation 16](https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/08/announcing-workstation-16-and-fusion-12.html) will support DirectX 11, which of August 2020 is expected to be released Q32020, which starts in October for VMWare.

Comment: You have to upgrade to the current version of Windows 10.  The new features of VMWare Workstation 16 require at least `Windows 10 version 1909` but you are running `Windows 10 version 1809` which does not support some of the newer features.  Having had tested this particular feature in the past, I can confirm, it does indeed work.

Comment: @Ramhound Everything you have mentioned is visible on the screenshots I’ve posted. vmware only provides D3D 10. I’m using current experimental build, just checked again, https://bit.ly/get-workstation-tp still redirects to VMware-workstation-full-e.x.p-16540321.exe. Windows is 10.0.18362.

Comment: Your screenshot indicates IE is 11.379.17763.0 which means you running 1809.  Any event "Windows 10 20H1 from Windows insider program.  Minimum build number: 19041." is what is required for the VMWare Workstation 20H2 experimental build.

Comment: @Ramhound Good point. I’m running 10.0.18362 on the host, visible in the third screenshot, in comments. I haven’t installed Windows in the guest, downloaded the image pre-made by MS from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ Too bad Microsoft failed to keep their images current. Thanks for the tip, will try to install the guest myself.

Comment: [Be sure you have installed the Nvidia and/or AMD GPU drives within the VM.](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-41686)

Comment: @Ramhound It was the OS image I got from MS. Made another VM, installed Win10 manually, and got my D3D 11. It has bugs, but I was able to workaround. Hope they’ll fix before release. https://communities.vmware.com/message/2980466#2980466 Thanks for your help.